# Windows 10 - gratis app to keep touchpad always active

Tags: gratis, windows-10, hardware

New laptop. It seems that a double tap can en/dis-able the touchpad.

Theoretically. In practice, I want it constantly enabled, but while my palm accidentally brushing against it disables it, double tapping does not always enable it.

I do have a function key combination to toggle it, but this is a ***major*** inconvenience when online gaming.

Is there an app which will detect when it becomes disabled & automagically enable it?

[image]

Comment: Have you try to disable power management for the USB port where touch pad is connected?

Comment: It is built into my laptop, not connected  by USB

Comment: Check your device manager and with 99% sure will be connected to USB

Comment: Nope. It's "human interface deceives". Thanks for trying to help, though, I do appreciate it

Comment: What is human interface device Windows 10?
Human Interface Devices (HID) is a device class definition to replace PS/2-style connectors with a generic USB driver to support HID devices such as keyboards, mice, game controllers, etc - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/